# Paragraph count issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to achieve the vertical middle advertisement between the dynamic content.

```js
if ($('#outer').find("p").length > 0) {     
    var p_count = $('#outer').find('p').length;
    var nth_ptag = Math.round(p_count / 2);
    alert(nth_ptag);
    $("#advt").insertAfter("p:nth-child(" + nth_ptag + ")");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="outer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum</a> party at the <a href="http://www.test.in" target="_blank">sed diam voluptua</a>. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <p>. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br/>        
        <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="advt" align="center" style="width:300px; height:250px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color:#CCC;">YourAdHere</div>
```

1. I have 6 paragraph tags in my example
2. Equally divide by 2

Question:
why calculated a href tags in top of the div area? Its insertAfter 1nd p tag.
I want to calculate only p tags.

Expected:
Its insertAfter 3nd p tag

Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this???

Comment: Don't bypass the *JSFiddle links must be accompanied by code* warning by posting your JSFiddle link within a code block. I've edited your answer to comment the JSFiddle link out. Please edit your question to include the appropriate code.

Comment: Looking at your previously asked questions (where answers were given and no reaction from you), I would like to ask you something : Do you really know what you want to achieve when you are asking for help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#advt").insertAfter("p:nth-child(" + nth_ptag + ")");
```

instead of

```
$("#advt").insertAfter("p:nth-of-type(" + nth_ptag + ")");
```